# Reincarnation book about a young girl dying from a lung disease who finds out about her prior lives

Tags: story-identification, books, reincarnation

I read a book with the word “pearl” in the title starting with a young girl dying from a lung disease and then finding out about her prior lives. At least 20-30 years ago. After death she finds herself alone in a pavilion on an island where she heals and then an Asian man appears to help her on her journey to explore past lives.

Comment: Whilst a nice overview this is pretty terse. Can you remember anything that happens in the plot? You say she finds out about prior lives, how?  etc. Could you [edit] your question to add in more detail?

Answer (score 4):

Most likely [Song of the Pearl](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?886186) by *Ruth Nichols*. Asthmatic girl, Margaret Redmond, dies at 17. Finds herself in "heaven", remembering other lives.
Paul, a Chinese man is there to meet her.

[image: Book cover]

Comment: If this is the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.